# Ubuntu 11.10 OpenVPN config

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying to setup a vpn server with an old box I have at my office. I only have a single ethernet port and saw on reddit that it was possible to use only one to create a vpn server.

The problem is that my router is set at 192.168.1.1 and in `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` I have `server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0`. It automatically sets the TUN interface to 192.168.1.1 and I think thats is conflicting with the router IP. Is there a way around that by possibly setting that ip to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, changing that will fix your problem.  I'm not sure if its a hard requirement but you should set your address pool for the VPN to something other than that of your LAN.

At home my IP range is 192.168.100.0 and here is the OpenVPN settings I use:

```
server 10.167.111.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0"
```

When I connect to the VPN, I can still access all the resources on my network, but my address pool for VPN is isolated from the LAN. See [Expanding the scope of the VPN to include additional machines on either the client or server subnet.](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope)

Comment: So far so good. No more network conflicts. now I just have to check the actual VPN tunnel.